# Getting ICE failed in webrtc P2P video calling when communicating in different network

Tags: socket.io, webrtc

I'm working to create a video calling web app using WebRTC.

The communication is working fine on same network. But when communicating in different network I'm getting `ICE failed` error.

> Error: `ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details`

In `about:webrtc` I' able to get local and remote SDP's, but `ICE State` is `failed`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKGa2.jpg

[Here is the code of my `main.js` file](https://gist.github.com/AtulKsol/efe99e4eae75a328023e6abeb835fd21)

[Here is the my log file from `about:webrtc`](https://gist.github.com/AtulKsol/5f329367fbf6f7658b24475f22cad18c)

P.S: Before posting the question I've checked several posts in SO and in other sites but no one did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log file you provided it looks like you provided a TURN server, but the communication with that TURN server simply times out. So either something like a local firewall is blocking the communication with your TURN server or your TURN server is not working.

In case your local firewall blocks UDP traffic it might help to configure and use TURN TCP additionally to get through the firewall.

Comment: I'll try another TURN server. But if I'm using STUN server, then shouldn't the communication be initiated using STUN? Or my STUN is also failing? Currently I'm using `{urls:["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}` as my STUN server.

Comment: The log shows that communication with the STUN server is working. You get so called server reflexive candidates from the STUN server back. But the firewalls/NAT's in front of your private networks are so restrictive that STUN is not enough to establish a working channel between both clients. The logs from Phillip's comment below show that credentials for the free TURN server actually don't work.

Comment: So, it seems STUN will work if I'll go in less-restrictive network. Right? Now do I need set up my own TURN server or public TURN servers are available?

Comment: You can either setup your own TURN server, or you can buy that as a service from external providers. TURN servers services are not generally not available free of charge, because they cost the service provider quite a bit of money for the bandwidth you consume.

Answer (score 0):

your about:webrtc does not show any relay candidates gathered from a TURN server. At the risk of sounding like a broken record: you need a TURN server for the majority of connections between different networks.

Comment: Seems like I'm using expired TURN server unless firewall is blocking the connection. Although I'll change my TURN server. But if I'm using STUN server, then shouldn't the communication be initiated using STUN? Or my STUN is also failing? Currently I'm using `{urls:["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}` as my STUN server.

Comment: when you say "change your turn server", are you running your own or trying to use one from a list of "free turn servers"? There is no such thing.
Add your credentials on 
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
remove the stun server and click "gather". see if you get candidates with type srflx and relay. If not your turn server does not work.

Comment: I'm using one of the public TURN server. `{urls: "turn:173.194.72.127:19305?transport=udp", username:"CKjCuLwFEgahxNRjuTAYzc/s6OMT", credential:"u1SQDR/SQsPQIxXNWQT7czc/G4c="}`. Do I need set up my own TURN server?

Comment: And yes I tried to put TURN server details in webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-‌​ice but I didn't get any candidates with type srflx and relay. [Here is what I'm getting from there.](https://imgur.com/a/A6Pzd)

Comment: this TURN server is no longer running. The list of public turn servers is basically a hoax.

Comment: Ohhh. So seems like setting-up my own TURN server is the only hope. I'll use [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) to set up TURN server. Please let me know if I'm going wrong.